# CXF multiple implementors for one address

Tags: web-services, cxf

is it possible to have multiple implementors with only one address ?
So something like:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="ws1" implementor="#ws1" address="/ws" />
<jaxws:endpoint id="ws2" implementor="#ws2" address="/ws" />
```

Thanks
--MB

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Which implementation should handle requests to `/ws`?

Comment: depends on the method called. i am just trying to have one end-point and yet multiple java implementation classes, so that i dont end up with 5000 line long file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a huge endpoint with lots of operations. If you do *contract first* development, CXF will create a single class per each endpoint, containing one method per operation. I believe this is the only way. You can however use this endpoint class only as a facade, delegating to several specialized classes (one line per operation, that's it).

Of course you can always refactor your WSDL to have multiple endpoints, but probably this is not an option for you. As far as I know there is no way to split implementation into several classes, the class must implement WS interface entirely.

In Spring WS however any method can handle SOAP request by annotating it with `@PayloadRoot` inside a class annotated with `@Endpoint`. This looks like a great feature in your case, since you can span implementation in as many classes as you want (even one class per SOAP operation!)